# Using Maximum Mean Discrepancy (MMD) to Compare Kernel Density Estimates (KDEs)

Tags: distribution, kernel

I'm interested in comparing two `Kernel Density Estimates (KDEs)` and I've come across the `Maximum Mean Discrepancy (MMD)` metric as a potential method for doing so. However, I'm unsure about the applicability. Can MMD be used to compare KDEs? If so, what considerations should I be aware of when using MMD to compare KDEs
I appreciate any insights, advice, or examples that can help me better understand and apply MMD in the context of comparing KDEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can MMD be used to compare KDEs?**

Yes, the MMD metric can be used to compare KDEs. MMD is a distance measure between distributions and is defined as the distance between their embeddings in the Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space (RKHS)
[[1]](https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v13/gretton12a.html). It is a form of integral probability metric and can be computed in quadratic time, although efficient linear time approximations are available . The MMD can be used to construct statistical tests to determine if two samples are drawn from different distributions, making it applicable for comparing KDEs [[1]](https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v13/gretton12a.html).

**Considerations when using MMD to compare KDEs**

When using MMD to compare KDEs, there are several considerations to be aware of:

- **Choice of Kernel Function**: The choice of kernel function used in the MMD calculation can impact the results. Different kernel functions can be used, and the selection should be based on the specific characteristics of the data being compared [[1]](https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v13/gretton12a.html).
- **Bandwidth Selection**: The bandwidth parameter used in the kernel density estimation can affect the performance of MMD. It's important to carefully consider the bandwidth selection to ensure accurate comparison of the KDEs [[2]](https://aakinshin.net/posts/kde-bw/).
- **Sample Size**: The sample size used for estimating the KDEs can influence the MMD calculation. Larger sample sizes can lead to more accurate estimates of the MMD
- **Interpretation of Results**: It's crucial to interpret the results of the MMD comparison in the context of the specific problem or application. Understanding the implications of the MMD values in relation to the compared KDEs is essential for drawing meaningful conclusions [[1]](https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v13/gretton12a.html).

By considering these factors, the MMD metric can be effectively utilized to compare Kernel Density Estimates and provide insights into the differences between distributions.

I hope this information helps you :)